# Another approach for simple MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

> I'm looking for another approach to write this query **(should run on MySQL)**, The approach can be *worse* then what I already have as long as its different and still gives the correct answer, there aren't restrictions on the approach.

## My query:

**The query finds the average of student in each subject and also finds the average of averages per subject per student:**

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.totalAvg 
FROM (SELECT StudentFirstName,StudentLastName,ClassName,AVG(Grade) AS `average for this subject`
      FROM tests
      INNER JOIN students ON tests.StudentID=students.StudentID
      GROUP BY StudentFirstName,StudentLastName,ClassName
     ) t1
JOIN (SELECT StudentFirstName,StudentLastName,AVG(`average for this subject`) as totalAvg
      FROM (SELECT StudentFirstName,StudentLastName,ClassName,AVG(Grade) AS `average for this subject`
            FROM tests
            INNER JOIN students ON tests.StudentID=students.StudentID
            GROUP BY StudentFirstName,StudentLastName,ClassName
           ) t
      GROUP BY StudentFirstName,StudentLastName
     ) t2 
ON t1.StudentFirstName=t2.StudentFirstName and t1.StudentLastName=t2.StudentLastName;
```

**Students table:**

```
  pk-INT           VARCHAR             VARCHAR
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| StudentID | StudentFirstName | StudentLastName |
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
|         1 | agam             | rafaeli         |
|         2 | amir             | aizinger        |
|         3 | avi              | caspi           |
|         4 | avia             | wolf            |
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
```

**Tests table:**

```
  PK-VARCHR    PK-VARCHR     PK&FK-INT   INT
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| TestDate   | ClassName  | StudentID | Grade |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| 2017-07-01 | Algebra    |         1 |    88 |
| 2017-08-02 | Algo       |         1 |    97 |
| 2017-09-01 | Algebra    |         1 |    80 |
| 2017-09-01 | Algebra    |         1 |    97 |
| 2017-09-01 | Set-theory |         1 |    85 |
| 2017-09-04 | Calcules   |         1 |    86 |
| 2016-05-03 | Set-theory |         2 |    84 |
| 2016-07-02 | Calcules   |         2 |    89 |
| 2016-07-04 | Algo       |         2 |    83 |
| 2016-07-05 | Algebra    |         2 |    79 |
| 2016-06-03 | Algebra    |         3 |    99 |
| 2016-07-02 | Algo       |         3 |    97 |
| 2016-07-03 | Calcules   |         3 |    96 |
| 2016-09-03 | Set-theory |         3 |    95 |
| 2016-06-03 | Algebra    |         4 |    78 |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
```

## SAMPLE DATA:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS error404;
CREATE DATABASE error404;
USE error404
CREATE TABLE students
(
    StudentID        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    StudentFirstName VARCHAR(25),
    StudentLastName  VARCHAR(25),
    PRIMARY KEY (StudentID)
);
INSERT INTO students (StudentFirstName,StudentLastName) VALUES
('agam'  , 'rafaeli'), ('amir'  , 'aizinger'), ('avi'   , 'caspi'),
('avia'  , 'wolf ');
CREATE TABLE tests
(
    testid    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TestDate  DATE,
    ClassName VARCHAR(25),
    StudentID INT NOT NULL,
    Grade     INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (testid),
    KEY (StudentID)
);
INSERT INTO tests (TestDate,ClassName,StudentID,Grade) VALUES
('2017-07-01', 'Algebra'    , 1 , 88 ), ('2017-08-02', 'Algo'       , 1 , 97 ),
('2017-09-01', 'Algebra'    , 1 , 80 ), ('2017-09-01', 'Algebra'    , 1 , 97 ),
('2017-09-01', 'Set-theory' , 1 , 85 ), ('2017-09-04', 'Calcules'   , 1 , 86 ),
('2016-05-03', 'Set-theory' , 2 , 84 ), ('2016-07-02', 'Calcules'   , 2 , 89 ),
('2016-07-04', 'Algo'       , 2 , 83 ), ('2016-07-05', 'Algebra'    , 2 , 79 ),
('2016-06-03', 'Algebra'    , 3 , 99 ), ('2016-07-02', 'Algo'       , 3 , 97 ),
('2016-07-03', 'Calcules'   , 3 , 96 ), ('2016-09-03', 'Set-theory' , 3 , 95 ),
('2016-06-03', 'Algebra'    , 4 , 78 );
```

Comment: Did you have an actual question that's within the scope defined by the [help/on-topic]?  Because SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: You have asked this question several times.  I don't get why you are still looking for inefficient ways to do this?  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192616/another-way-to-write-avg-query https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192661/average-of-averages-from-joining-two-tables

Comment: It's not the same queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delay use of the students table, most of the calculations do not require student names.

```
SELECT
      s.StudentFirstName
    , s.StudentLastName
    , t1.ClassName
    , t1.student_class_avg AS `average for this subject`
    , t2.student_avg_avg   AS totalAvg
FROM students s
INNER JOIN (SELECT StudentID,ClassName,AVG(Grade) AS student_class_avg
      FROM tests
      GROUP BY StudentID,ClassName
     ) t1 ON s.StudentID = t1.StudentID
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT StudentID,AVG(student_class_avg) AS student_avg_avg
      FROM (
            SELECT StudentID,ClassName,AVG(Grade) AS student_class_avg
            FROM tests
            GROUP BY StudentID,ClassName
           ) t
      GROUP BY StudentID
     ) t2 ON s.StudentID = t2.StudentID
ORDER BY 
      s.StudentFirstName
    , s.StudentLastName
    , t1.ClassName
;
```